# Slow performance of Nginx when using Source Maps in production

Tags: nginx, tcp, webpack, production, source-maps

I have a problem with Nginx and source maps. I wanted to use them in production for debugging. They are not actually downloaded until you open a Chrome dev tools and that is ok. The problem start when I open the dev tools and try to refresh page 2 or 3 times in a row. Everything slows down, page needs a long time to load. 
As far as I saw it the problem is with ssl_socket_pool and chrome limitation of 6 connections at the same time. I only have one bundle file and bundle.js.map file. Why is this a problem? If I don't use Nginx everything is working fine?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this issue? I'm seeing something similar. Thanks.